# insert text in specific location

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I have a TextView with some text. I have a button that must insert a word. The problem is that with "stringByAppendingString" I can't enter the single word at the cursor location without deleting what's before and after.

Is there any method to insert text in the location you want?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use something like:

```
NSMutableString *string1 = [NSMutableString stringWithString: @"The quick brown fox jumped"];

[string1 insertString: @"agile, " atIndex: 4];
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the string in which you want to insert your word using ' text ' property of ' text View ' then use the 'insertString:atIndex:' property of string and replace the textview text. . . . Hope this may helps you